# Angular js get request with headers- showing CORS error

Tags: angularjs, http, get, http-headers

In my angular controller code my http get method not working with header but the same request working in postman

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/profiles',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer 78954642-sf25-4sd6-sdf2-99582369d5af',
     'Content-Type':'text/plain'
    }
   }).then(function(success) {
     console.log(success);
  }, function(error) {
  });
```

**Showing following error**

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://quotebuilder' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

My request header

```
OPTIONS /api/profiles HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://quotebuilder
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://quotebuilder/login
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

What is wrong here ? please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: You need to install CORS plugin from chrome or the CORS should be enabled from the API.

Comment: I think you can just pass response headers and it should work. It worked for me when I added `.headers(Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")` in my `response` headers and if that does not work then edit your web.xml file (if using tomcat).

Answer (score 2):

Your should make CORS disabled  in your server side to make this work. A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain, or port than the one which the first resource itself serves see dtails [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you are using spring or other server side web frameworks you need to disable that  from there.

Comment: Yes it's CORS related issue, you have to change CORS settings on server side. for example if you are using tomcat, edit web.xml file to include CORS tag. another workaround is to disable web security on Chrome

Comment: yes but if you are going to deploy it to a production server you should not use hack that might come back to haunt you @playerone

Comment: you are right :) he should disable chrome security only for development mode